# Extra space characters in MS Word translations document

Tags: formatting, ms-word, character, symbols

I have some MS Word documents that were translated from other languages and when I click to turn on the paragraph/hidden formatting symbols setting I see a lot of added little circles where space holders for foreign punctuation would be (it looks like the degree symbol). I want to do some kind of mass delete for these extra spaces/circles. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: this site is for questions related to programming, not the usage of programmes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume since they aren't "real" that you can't just ctrl+c the little circles and then do a ctrl+h find&replace and replace them with nothing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since they aren't "real" I can't cut and find/replace them. It would like trying to find/replace the actual paragraph symbol which is why I am having some problems. It is very frustrating... :(

Comment: You can find/replace the paragraph symbol with ^p which is listed if you click the "Special" button at the bottom of the Find and Replace window. Maybe one of those options helps with your original question as well.

Comment: That was it -- it worked!! Thank you so much. I needed to remove "non breaking space" which is ^s . Thanks again!